# Connectives in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How do I translate the following to predicate logic:

D(x) - x is a bus driver

P(x) - x is a passenger

There are no passengers but there is a bus driver.

For the passengers ¬∃x P(x) and ∃ D(x) for the driver, but how do I join the two with the connective "but".

Comment: "X but not Y" can be translated as "X and not Y." Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Is ¬∃x ∃y P(x) ∧ D(y) sound?

Comment: If you mean, $(\neg\exists x Px) \wedge (\exists x Dx),$ then yes.

Comment: @logic-italia ¬∃x ∃y P(x) ∧ D(y) is not quite correct.  That is like saying "There does not exist a bus driver for which there are passengers."  It includes the possibility that there are zero bus drivers and zero passengers, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The English word "but" is formally symbolized as a conjunction in predicate logic.

Therefore the correct symbolization is as follows:

$$\neg \exists x P(x) \wedge \exists x D(x)$$

This means there doesn't exist an x such that x is a passenger (there are no passengers) and there exists an x such that there is a bus driver (there is at least one bus driver).